# How to create Drawable from resource

Tags: android, drawable

I have an image `res/drawable/test.png` (R.drawable.test).
I want to pass this image to a function which accepts `Drawable`, e.g. `mButton.setCompoundDrawables()`.

So how can I convert an image resource to a `Drawable`?

Answer (score 620, accepted):

Your Activity should have the method getResources. Do:

```
Drawable myIcon = getResources().getDrawable( R.drawable.icon );
```

---

---

As of API version 21 this method is deprecated and can be replaced with:

```
Drawable myIcon = AppCompatResources.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.icon);
```

If you need to specify a custom theme, the following will apply it, but only if API is version 21 or greater:

```
Drawable myIcon =  ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.icon, theme);
```

Comment: Do you need to add something else to the manifest for instance? I created an empty project with only this line of code in onCreate and I get Resources$NotFoundException. The project came with icon.png in hdpi, ldpi and mdpi map.

Comment: If you happen to want this outside of an Activity class, you'll have to find some other way to reach the Context where getResources() lives; [this answer recommends passing it into the constructor](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6214567/404960)

Comment: As of API version 21 this method is deprecated and you should be replaced by:

Drawable drawable = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), page.getImageId(), null);

Comment: @Boren is it the same as to use ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.icon);?

Comment: @Boren This is also OK: Drawable myIcon = getResources().getDrawable( R.drawable.icon, null );

Comment: None of the above suggestions seem to work if R.drawable.icon is a Vector drawable.

Comment: DON'T USE THIS IF YOU ARE USING VECTOR DRAWABLE. Use AppCompatResources.getDrawable(context,  R.drawable.icon ) instead.

Comment: getDrawable() is deprecated as of Lollipop.

Comment: @DhavalPatel May you please explain why to use `AppCompatResources.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.icon ) `

Comment: @KwnstantinosNikoloutsos It will throw android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException for vector resources.

Answer (score 142):

This code is deprecated:

```
Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable( R.drawable.icon );
```

Use this instead:

```
Drawable drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(),R.drawable.icon);
```

Comment: Be aware that this will apply the theme from the given context. If you want to ensure no theme is used, you can use `ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.icon, null);` (where the 3rd param is an optional Theme instance).

Answer (score 23):

The `getDrawable (int id)` method is deprecated as of API 22.

Instead you should use the `getDrawable (int id, Resources.Theme theme)` for API 21+

Code would look something like this.

```
Drawable myDrawable;
if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP){
    myDrawable = context.getResources().getDrawable(id, context.getTheme());
} else {
    myDrawable = context.getResources().getDrawable(id);
}
```

Comment: why not pass null for every api? Plus: Are you sure that null is the best option?

Comment: The getDrawable(int id, Resources.Theme theme) didn't come about until API 21.

Comment: or `getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_warning_80dp, context?.theme)`

Answer (score 14):

I would just like to add that if you are getting "deprecated" message when using getDrawable(...) you should use the following method from the support library instead.

```
ContextCompat.getDrawable(getContext(),R.drawable.[name])
```

You do not have to use getResources() when using this method.

This is equivalent to doing something like

```
Drawable mDrawable;
if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP){
    mDrawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(getContext(),R.drawable.[name]);
} else {
    mDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.id.[name]);
}
```

This works on both pre and post Lollipop versions.

Answer (score 5):

**Get Drawable from vector resource irrespective of, whether its vector or not:**

```
AppCompatResources.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.icon);
```

**Note:**
    `ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.icon);` will produce `android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException` for vector resource.

Comment: Excellent answer!!

Answer (score 4):

If you are trying to get the drawable from the view where the image is set as,

```
ivshowing.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.one);
```

then the drawable will return only null value with the following code...

```
   Drawable drawable = (Drawable) ivshowing.getDrawable();
```

So, it's better to set the image with the following code, if you wanna retrieve the drawable from a particular view.

```
 ivshowing.setImageResource(R.drawable.one);
```

only then the drawable will we converted exactly.

Answer (score 2):

If you are inheriting from a fragment you can do:

`Drawable drawable = getActivity().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon)`

Comment: That's worked for me, after Android Studio suggestion it converts to requireActivity()!!.getDrawable(R.drawable.id)

Answer (score 2):

You must get it via compatible way, others are deprecated:

```
Drawable drawable = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(context.getResources(), R.drawable.my_drawable, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

In **Kotlin** you can do like this:

```
binding.floatingActionButton.setImageDrawable(
            AppCompatResources.getDrawable(this, android.R.drawable.ic_delete))
```

Where `binding` is a root View and this refer to `Context`, You need **import**

```
import androidx.appcompat.content.res.AppCompatResources
```