# How to access drawable from non activity class

Tags: android, drawable

I am in a situation where I have to use the `drawable folder` of my app form a non activity class. I tried using the parent activity with the following code:

```
ParentActivity pa = new ParentActivity();
Drawable d = pa.getResources()..getDrawable(R.drawable.icon);`
```

But this returns me a `NulLPointerException`. 
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Pass the context object as a parameter  to the constructor of the non Activity class.

Then use that context object to get the Resources.

Example

```
public class MyClass {
  Context context;
  public MyClass(Context context) {
      this.context = context;
  }

  public void urMethod() {
    Drawable drawable=context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon);
    // use this drawable as u need
  }
}
```

Comment: Is it just me or the "R" or (whatever resources are called in Java) is imported into the class so this is not generic at all?

Comment: Note that from API 22, the right way to get drawables is:
`Drawable drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.icon)`

Answer (score 4):

```
import com.(package-name).R;
```

then you can access all your drawable e.g     R.drawable.icon.

Comment: This access the resource as integer, not the actual drawable.