# Calling setCompoundDrawables() doesn't display the Compound Drawable

Tags: android, android-layout, android-drawable

After I call the [`setCompoundDrawables`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setCompoundDrawables%28android.graphics.drawable.Drawable,%20android.graphics.drawable.Drawable,%20android.graphics.drawable.Drawable,%20android.graphics.drawable.Drawable%29) method, the compound Drawable is not shown..

```
Drawable myDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.btn);
btn.setCompoundDrawables(myDrawable, null, null, null);
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: As stated in the answers below, the variant of the method named `(..)WithIntrinsicBounds` needs to be called. On a side note, `padding` for the Compound Drawable must be set **after** this call to cause an effect

Comment: The [document](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setCompoundDrawables%28android.graphics.drawable.Drawable,%20android.graphics.drawable.Drawable,%20android.graphics.drawable.Drawable,%20android.graphics.drawable.Drawable%29) says: *The Drawables must already have had [`setBounds(Rect)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.html#setBounds(android.graphics.Rect)) called.*

Comment: hi hunterp, just met you at coffee shop (Angel), now that I know you know what Android Drawables are (and perhaps you've hit memory out of error errors when working with many of them), I can tell you about some of the projects I've collaborated had to deal with this issue, check out https://github.com/JakeWharton/DiskLruCache (which I collaborated to make more android friendly) which is used by Picasso (https://github.com/square/picasso)

Comment: @Dr1Ku Actually I have it before and is works anyway.

Comment: Please see this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/71966649/12272687

Answer (score 708, accepted):

I needed to be using [`setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView#setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(int,%20int,%20int,%20int)).

Comment: thankyou very much .. this works for me.. may i know whats the difference between these two ?

Comment: @user1324936 The 'relative' version requires API 17, others can be used with previous versions

Comment: @user1324936  setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds was added in **API Level 3**

Comment: I was using setCompoundDrawableRelativeWithIntrinsicBounds <- this one was added on API 17. Be careful of the intellisense.

Comment: its working thanks. what's the difference between them

Comment: SetcCompoundDrawable ducomentation: Sets the Drawables (if any) to appear to the left of, above, to the right of, and below the text. Use null if you do not want a Drawable there. The Drawables must already have had setBounds(Rect) called. setBounds() is not called on your drawables.

Answer (score 76):

Use This (I tested). It works good

```
Drawable image = context.getResources().getDrawable( R.drawable.ic_action );
int h = image.getIntrinsicHeight(); 
int w = image.getIntrinsicWidth();   
image.setBounds( 0, 0, w, h );
button.setCompoundDrawables( image, null, null, null );
```

Comment: This is useful when targeting APIs lower than 17, since `EditText#setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds` requires at least API 17.

Comment: Can you provide a source for that? All the documentation I've seen indicates this has been [available since API 1](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html).

Answer (score 52):

Image is blank because it hasn't got specified bounds. You may use `setCompoundDrawables()` but before you should specify image's bounds, using `Drawable.setBounds()` method

Comment: Best answer because you actually provide the reasoning as to why setBounds is important.

Comment: @Andy Exactly, hate these top answers with 800 votes that just copy pasted one code line without any words

Answer (score 48):

Example set to the top:

```
view.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(
    null,
    getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.some_img),
    null,
    null
);
```

arguments order: (left, top, right, bottom)

Comment: this should be the accepted answer, in my case using button. and it workeds as expected!!!

It also backward compatibility.

Answer (score 24):

A little bit simpler again:

```
Drawable image = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_action );
image.setBounds( 0, 0, image.getIntrinsicWidth(), image.getIntrinsicHeight() );
button.setCompoundDrawables( image, null, null, null );
```

Answer (score 20):

The Image is not shown as you didn't specify the bounds, so you have 2 options here.

**1st Method**

Use `setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds` method, as shown below

```
Drawable myDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.btn);
btn. setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(myDrawable, null, null, null);
```

**2nd Method**

You can apply bounds to the drawable before applying to the TextView, as shown below

```
Drawable myDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.btn);
myDrawable.setBounds( 0, 0, myDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), myDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight());
btn.setCompoundDrawables(myDrawable, null, null, null);
```

That's it.

Comment: Nice you actually included examples and the pre API 17 implementation which more directly addressed the setCompoundDrawables method.

Answer (score 11):

It is deprecated in API 22.

This code is useful for me:

```
Drawable drawable = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(),R.drawable.wen, null);
drawable.setBounds(0, 0, drawable.getMinimumWidth(),
drawable.getMinimumHeight());
tv.setCompoundDrawables(drawable, null, null, null);
```

Answer (score 4):

In Kotlin:

1) Set `drawable`:

```
val drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context!!,R.drawable.ic_image)?.apply {
    setBounds(0, 0, intrinsicWidth, intrinsicHeight)
}
```

or

```
val drawable = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(resources, R.drawable.ic_image, null)?.apply {
    setBounds(0, 0, minimumWidth, minimumHeight)
}
```

2) Set `TextView`:

```
textView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(drawable, null, null, null)
```

or

```
button.setCompoundDrawables(null, drawable, null, null)
```

Comment: For Textview `setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds` will worked..

Answer (score 3):

For me [setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(Drawable, Drawable, Drawable, Drawable)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable,%20android.graphics.drawable.Drawable,%20android.graphics.drawable.Drawable,%20android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)) did not work.

I had to use [setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, 0, 0)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(int,%20int,%20int,%20int)).

Comment: What for? For removing a drawable?

Answer (score 2):

Example with Kotlin:

```
    val myView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.my_view, null) as TextView
    myView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, myDrawable, 0, 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

In **Kotlin** with **Databinding**

```
binding.tvTime.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(
            ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(resources, android.R.drawable.ic_menu_recent_history, null),
            null,null,null)
```

where `tvTime` is `textView` and Position `(Rigth,Top,Left,Bottom)`, More about **binding** is here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/72360048/12272687