# Custom AppCompatRadioButton with Toggle Drawable right of text

Tags: android, android-custom-view, android-radiobutton

I'm try to set `Toggle Drawable' to right of AppCompatRadioButton' text with

```
public class mRadioButton extends AppCompatRadioButton {

public mRadioButton(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
}
...

private void init() {
    setButtonDrawable(null);
    int padding = Constant.calculateDimen(getContext(), 20.0);
    setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);
    setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
    setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(-1, -1));

    int[] attrs = { android.R.attr.listChoiceIndicatorSingle };
    TypedArray ta = getContext().getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs);
    Drawable indicatorDrawable = ta.getDrawable(0);
    setCompoundDrawables(null, null, indicatorDrawable, null);
    ta.recycle();
}
```

}

But ultimately , no Toggle Drawable appears :

[image]

And if set comment `setButtonDrawable(null);` add Toggle left of text :

[image]

And set `setButtonDrawable(indicator);` appears Toggle Drawable both left an right of text:

[image]

What's going on , whats wrong and what to do?

Comment: Have you tried this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6599782/9119277)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With thanks @Napster i change :

```
setCompoundDrawables(null, null, indicatorDrawable, null);
```

To :

```
setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null,null,indicatorDrawable,null);
```

---

### But Whay!?

**Then i searched for what happened , that found this :**

Manually set the relative position of text and pictures, commonly used methods are as follows:

```
setCompoundDrawables(left, top, right, bottom);


setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(left, top, right, bottom);
```

The meaning is to set the Drawable display on the text, on the left, right, down position.

But the two are different:

1. `setCompoundDrawables` Paint drawable's width and height is drawable.setBound () set the width and height, 
   So there are The Drawables must already have had setBounds(Rect) called.
   You must use the `Drawable.setBounds` to set the Drawable before using the length and width.
2. `setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBoundsDraw` drawable's width and height is drawable fixed width and height, 
   So just have The Drawables' bounds will be set to their intrinsic bounds.