# How do I insert an image in an activity with android studio?

Tags: android, image, android-layout

I am very new to android development, and have only read and completed the first guide in the android development site. The problem I have been having is that I can not put a picture in an activity. I have the picture in my drawables folder. I just don't know how to get it on the screen. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4818118/how-to-create-drawable-from-resource)

Comment: "put a picture in an intent" does not sound right.

Comment: "I have the picture in my drawables folder. I just don't know how to get it on the screen" -- then why do you think that you need "an image in an `Intent`"? Put the image in an `ImageView` in your activity, either via `android:src` in your layout file or `setImageResource()` on the `ImageView`.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

since you followed the tutorial, I presume you have a screen that says Hello World.

that means you have some code in your layout xml that looks like this

```
<TextView        
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />
```

you want to display an image, so instead of TextView you want to have ImageView. and instead of a text attribute you want an src attribute, that links to your drawable resource

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/cool_pic"
/>
```

Answer (score 11):

I'll Explain how to add an image using Android studio(2.3.3). First you need to add the image into **res/drawable** folder in the project. Like below

[image]

Now in go to activity_main.xml (or any activity you need to add image) and select the **Design** view. There you can see your Palette tool box on left side. You need to drag and drop ImageView.

[image]

It will prompt you **Resources** dialog box. In there select **Drawable** under the project section you can see your image. Like below

[image]

Select the image you want press **Ok** you can see the image on the **Design** view. If you want it configure using xml it would look like below.

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/homepage"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="55dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="130dp" />
```

You need to give image location using

```
app:srcCompat="@drawable/imagename"
```

Answer (score 0):

When you have image into yours drawable gallery then you just need to pick the option of image view pick and drag into app activity you want to show and select the required image.

Answer (score 0):

copy the image that you want to show in android app and paste in drawable folder. given below code

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/image"
 />
```