# How to Get Image From Image Resource Id

Tags: android, image, android-intent, drawable, android-drawable

I had try somethimg like this I had seen example have its drawable name and find resource id ..Now I don't know drawable name I just have to find it from imgresourceId

This is my Image Resource Id

```
int id = Integer.parseInt(data.getStringExtra("imgId"));

05-30 12:09:33.648: D/imgid(5461): 2130837579
```

I want to set this to drawable right of a edittext

So I had done something like this

```
ed_operator.setCompoundDrawablesRelativeWithIntrinsicBounds( null, null, id, null );
```

3rd parameter is expecting drawable so how to convert this image resource id to drawable

is there any alternative solution which I can apply....

Comment: Can you post your xml code too? What is your image's name?

Comment: what did u have in "myImageList" array...?

Comment: i have an array of image @shobhan

Comment: what i mean is are they resource id's or names or drawables..?

Comment: check it @shobhan http://pastie.org/10214699

Comment: then simply put resource ID in intent. get it as getIntExtra("ID",-1).

Comment: possible the dublicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4818118/how-to-create-drawable-from-resource

Comment: @AngadTiwari that is not possible duplicate ..there you have you drawable image name nd you have to find resource id...here opposite...once again look at question

Comment: @Tufan It is a possible duplicate. In the post Angad linked, you have the id and you get the Drawable from the resources. "R.drawable.icon" IS the id. It's an integer number.

Comment: yes  @bilarion  ..i need it because i have to set this in edittext

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hey there you are putting resource ID (intenger) as extra. and getting with string extra. make it as

```
        int resID =  data.getIntExtra("imgId",-1);
        if(resID != -1 ){
          Drawable img = getResources().getDrawable( resID );
          img.setBounds( 0, 0, 60, 60 );

          ed_operator.setCompoundDrawablesRelativeWithIntrinsicBounds( null, null, img, null );//if you dont have images already in drawable 
          //OR
          ed_operator.setCompoundDrawables( null, null,img,null);//if you had set images in your drawable
        }
```

Comment: nope dude ..i had tried everything is fine but drawable is not set to drawable right ...although it shows get drawable is depricated

Comment: i already have a right drawable for edittext ..problem is this how can i replace this with my drawable..it is not replacing

Comment: i had check it but nthng hpnd is there anyway to replace exisiting image or remove image from right drawable ..so 1st i remove existing than i can set

Comment: i had edited your code review it..so i can accept it as answer

Comment: ed_operator.setCompoundDrawables( null, null,img,null);   you can apply this if you have an already drawable in your edittext

Answer (score 0):

To get an image from resources, and you know its id , you do the following in your Activity:

```
// Get the id.
int id = Integer.parseInt(data.getStringExtra("imgId"));
// Get the drawable from the id.
Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(id);
```

Comment: check my question i know its resource id ..how to convert this to drawables

Comment: If you know the resource id and you want to get the drawable from the resource id, this is the way. You have to clarify a bit.

Comment: The correct usage of setCompoundDrawablesRelative is setCompoundDrawablesRelative(Drawable, Drawable, Drawable, Drawable) and not setCompoundDrawablesRelative(int, int, int, int). So you have to get the drawable first from the id and then set it to Edit Text

Comment: this is my resource id 05-30 12:09:33.648: D/imgid(5461): 2130837579

Comment: this is my img resource id 05-30 12:09:33.648: D/imgid(5461): 2130837579
how to convert this to drawable

Comment: now its fine it convert imgid to drawable but can you tell me why this drawable is not displayed in ed_operator.setCompoundDrawablesRelativeWithIntrinsicBounds( null, null, id, null );     as right drawable

Comment: Maybe use the "wrap_content" attribute in EditText.

Comment: thats nt psble hey i got its name something like this  String name = getApplicationContext().getResources().getResourceEntryName(id);    can you tell me hot to convert this to drawable image

Comment: i already have a right drawable for edittext ..problem is this how can i replace this with my drawable..it is not replacing