# How can I get drawable in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, drawable, android-resources

I am working on a small project in Android Studio.
I have drawable added to res/drawable folder. 
[image]

However I cannot  get it from the code. I have tried different approaches:

```
ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.drawable.ic_training);
```

and

```
val drawable: Drawable? = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context.applicationContext, R.drawable.ic_training )
val drawable2: Drawable = R.drawable.ic_training
```

Both of them return an error unresolved reference.
Here is my XML file:

```
<vector
        android:id = "@+id/ic_training"
        android:alpha="0.85" android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportHeight="24.0" android:viewportWidth="24.0"
    android:width="24dp" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:name="ic_training"    >
    <path android:fillColor="#FF000000" android:pathData="M22,21c-1.11,0 -1.73,-0.37 -2.18,-0.64 -0.37,-0.22 -0.6,-0.36 -1.15,-0.36 -0.56,0 -0.78,0.13 -1.15,0.36 -0.46,0.27 -1.07,0.64 -2.18,0.64s-1.73,-0.37 -2.18,-0.64c-0.37,-0.22 -0.6,-0.36 -1.15,-0.36 -0.56,0 -0.78,0.13 -1.15,0.36 -0.46,0.27 -1.08,0.64 -2.19,0.64 -1.11,0 -1.73,-0.37 -2.18,-0.64 -0.37,-0.23 -0.6,-0.36 -1.15,-0.36s-0.78,0.13 -1.15,0.36c-0.46,0.27 -1.08,0.64 -2.19,0.64v-2c0.56,0 0.78,-0.13 1.15,-0.36 0.46,-0.27 1.08,-0.64 2.19,-0.64s1.73,0.37 2.18,0.64c0.37,0.23 0.59,0.36 1.15,0.36 0.56,0 0.78,-0.13 1.15,-0.36 0.46,-0.27 1.08,-0.64 2.19,-0.64 1.11,0 1.73,0.37 2.18,0.64 0.37,0.22 0.6,0.36 1.15,0.36s0.78,-0.13 1.15,-0.36c0.45,-0.27 1.07,-0.64 2.18,-0.64s1.73,0.37 2.18,0.64c0.37,0.23 0.59,0.36 1.15,0.36v2zM22,16.5c-1.11,0 -1.73,-0.37 -2.18,-0.64 -0.37,-0.22 -0.6,-0.36 -1.15,-0.36 -0.56,0 -0.78,0.13 -1.15,0.36 -0.45,0.27 -1.07,0.64 -2.18,0.64s-1.73,-0.37 -2.18,-0.64c-0.37,-0.22 -0.6,-0.36 -1.15,-0.36 -0.56,0 -0.78,0.13 -1.15,0.36 -0.45,0.27 -1.07,0.64 -2.18,0.64s-1.73,-0.37 -2.18,-0.64c-0.37,-0.22 -0.6,-0.36 -1.15,-0.36s-0.78,0.13 -1.15,0.36c-0.47,0.27 -1.09,0.64 -2.2,0.64v-2c0.56,0 0.78,-0.13 1.15,-0.36 0.45,-0.27 1.07,-0.64 2.18,-0.64s1.73,0.37 2.18,0.64c0.37,0.22 0.6,0.36 1.15,0.36 0.56,0 0.78,-0.13 1.15,-0.36 0.45,-0.27 1.07,-0.64 2.18,-0.64s1.73,0.37 2.18,0.64c0.37,0.22 0.6,0.36 1.15,0.36s0.78,-0.13 1.15,-0.36c0.45,-0.27 1.07,-0.64 2.18,-0.64s1.73,0.37 2.18,0.64c0.37,0.22 0.6,0.36 1.15,0.36v2zM8.67,12c0.56,0 0.78,-0.13 1.15,-0.36 0.46,-0.27 1.08,-0.64 2.19,-0.64 1.11,0 1.73,0.37 2.18,0.64 0.37,0.22 0.6,0.36 1.15,0.36s0.78,-0.13 1.15,-0.36c0.12,-0.07 0.26,-0.15 0.41,-0.23L10.48,5C8.93,3.45 7.5,2.99 5,3v2.5c1.82,-0.01 2.89,0.39 4,1.5l1,1 -3.25,3.25c0.31,0.12 0.56,0.27 0.77,0.39 0.37,0.23 0.59,0.36 1.15,0.36z"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#FF000000" android:pathData="M16.5,5.5m-2.5,0a2.5,2.5 0,1 1,5 0a2.5,2.5 0,1 1,-5 0"/>
</vector>
```

Comment: can you please check that is your drawable is in drawable folder or it got misplaced in some other folder?

Comment: Check if it's in drawable not drawable-v24 and any other folder with any modifier

Comment: The drawable is named after the file it is in, not the `android:id` element.

Comment: Please [edit] your question with the full error message. Is the error only shown in the editor or do you get the error when building the project?

Comment: Please see this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/71966649/12272687

Answer (score 6, accepted):

at first, check that drawable in the root drawable, not in xxx or something else

- remove id from Vector shape as well

in your Activity do

```
val drawble = resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_training,theme)
```

if in Fragment

```
val drawble = context!!.resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_training,context!!.theme)
```

Comment: Unresolved reference: resources

Comment: resources.getDrawable() is deprecated

Answer (score 10):

**Android SDK 30**

```
ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.name)
```

Comment: In my case `this` does not have a context, which is the whole point of this question IMHO.

Answer (score 3):

Also in **Kotlin** you can use this way: (**SDK 31**)

```
val shape: Drawable? =
            ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(resources, R.drawable.custom_progress_bar, null)
```

where **null** : drawables without theme attributes

However, This link is show google doc about it:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource#kotlin

Answer (score 2):

resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_training, theme) is deprecated
use this

```
ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.drawable.name)
```

Comment: tks bro!! So shortly & simply <3

Answer (score 0):

Didn't see this here, and it's what worked for me:

```
   var myShape = ContextCompat.getDrawable(
      applicationContext,
      R.drawable.shape_rectangle  //<-- name of xml file in res folder
   )
```